# Live USB won't boot properly on Asus EEE PC 1201HAB

Tags: 11.10, live-usb

For some reason, I never get an X session going. I see a bunch of startup text messages, then it just stops. I checked the Xorg.0.log and it looks like there's some issue with the vesa driver? I tried the 'nomodeset' boot option, that didn't help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Trying to manually "startx" results in these errors:

```
vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
```

Output of `lspci | grep -i vga`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

I heard this error has something to do with Linux kernel 3.0 and something about a kernel-based video driver?

Comment: Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: Interesting...can you get to a terminal(CTL+ALT+F1)?  If you can `lspci | grep VGA` and `lspci | grep vid` and post the output of whichever looks like it might identify your video card.

Comment: Please add the exact error messages from Xorg.0.log to your question.

Comment: @jippie Ok, see log errs above.

Comment: @aking1012 See edits above

Comment: Bounty expires in 9 hrs! Hoping to get an answer on this..

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score -1):

do you see black screen after boot-up ?
If yes, then just login use command --> `login <user-name>`
Then it will ask for password, so enter your password.

And then you will see `terminal`. Now type `startx`.

And everything works well you will see the GUI.

Comment: also check if Linux is installed properly on pendrive.